# AUTOMATIC_TUNING SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, performance, query-performance, query-store

IS it possible to force the correct plan in the stored procedure syntax?

because current I found the option only at the base level

```
ALTER DATABASE TEST SET AUTOMATIC_TUNING (FORCE_LAST_GOOD_PLAN = ON );
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4):

[Automatic Tuning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/automatic-tuning/automatic-tuning?view=sql-server-ver16) is one of the Intelligent Query Processing features and depends on the Query Store. As the name suggests, it's automatic, so you can't affect it.

If you already have a Query Store enabled, you can force a plan through [sp_query_store_force_plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-query-store-force-plan-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) or a GUI (which calls the same procedure in the background).

You can also use [Plan Guides](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/apply-a-fixed-query-plan-to-a-plan-guide?view=sql-server-ver16), but they are more cumbersome to use.